# How can a char pointer contain a string in it?

Tags: c

If I define a char pointer in a C program and initialize it to "some String"

Can someone explain how a char pointer that's supposed to hold an address in it can hold a string in it?

Isn't it a contradiction to the definition of a pointer? What am I missing here?

For example :

```
char pointer=" how is it possible at all ? ";
printf("%s",pointer);
```

Comment: A pointer is a sign. If you see a sign that says *Lake over there*, it doesn't mean the sign contains the lake.

Comment: A `char *` means *pointer to a `char`*, which means *address of a `char`*. At that address there may be one `char`, or there may be a whole row (array) of them consecutively in memory. In C, a string is an array of characters that end in a null (0). So a `char *` doesn't *contain* a string, but it can be the *address of* or *pointer to* a string. If you declare `char *p;` you need to set `p` to a valid address that contains or can hold the zero-terminated array of characters.

Comment: I assume by `char pointer` you actually mean `char *pointer`?

Comment: Above code what you have mentioned in your question cause UB. Please check your gcc for the warnings. : `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 char pointer=" how is it possible at all ? ";
              ^
: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%s",pointer);  `

Comment: yes by char pointer I mean char *pointer

Comment: @RespectEverybody you can [edit] your question and correct typos.

Answer (score 6):

String literals, like `"how is it possible at all ? "` are really arrays of read-only characters stored somewhere by the compiler.

When you do

```
char *pointer=" how is it possible at all ? ";
```

you initialize `pointer` to point to the first element of that array.

This is very similar to

```
char string[] = " how is it possible at all ? ";
char *pointer = &string[0];  // Make pointer point to the first character in the array
```

---

How pointers themselves work depends on the compiler and the target architecture, but most of the time they are simple integers whose value is the address of the memory they point to. Then the compiler handles them specially and translates usage of the pointers into the correct machine-code instructions to access the memory a pointer is pointing to.

---

Because string literals are read only, that's the reason you should really use `const char *` when making pointers to them. C allows plain non-constant `char *`, but then the compiler might not be able to detect attempts to modify the read-only literal, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char string[] = " how is it possible at all ?"; char *pointer = &string[0]; ` or `const char *pointer = " how is it possible at all ?"`?

Answer (score 1):

In the statement:

```
char *pointer=" how is it possible at all ? ";
```

`" how is it possible at all ? "` is a string literal and a string literal is an array of characters.

From [C Standards#6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

So, the string literal which is an array decays into pointer of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain how a char pointer that's supposed to hold an address in it can hold a string in it?

Another way to look at it, by analogy:  the same way a huge building can have a street address such as "123 Main Street".

The address is *where* it is - not how big it is.